# Python IndexError: list index out of range when looking at if statement

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

I'm having trouble overcoming this error. I'm doing a routine similar to the merge in mergesort. Maybe I'm instantiating something wrong. Here's the code:

```
def MergeAndCountSplitInv(arr, length):
    left = arr[0:length/2]
    right = arr[length/2+1: length]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    numSplitInv = 0
    newArray = [0] * length
    for k in range(len(arr)):
        if (left[i] < right[j]):
            #newArray.insert(k, left[i])
            newArray.append(left[i])
            i = i + 1
        else: #(right[j] < left[i]
            #newArray[k].insert(k, right[j])
            newArray.append(right[j])
            j = j + 1
            numSplitInv = numSplitInv + (length/2 - i)

    return ReturnValue(newArray, numSplitInv)
```

The error is given as:

`File "InversionCount.py", line 31, in MergeAndCountSplitInv
    if (left[i] < right[j]):
IndexError: list index out of range`

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is your understanding of slice indexes.  These two lines:

```
left = arr[0:length/2]
right = arr[length/2+1: length]
```

should be changed to:

```
left = arr[:length/2]
right = arr[length/2:]
```

The start index is included, and the end index is the first element *not* included in the slice, so to get a complete partition, you use the same index for the end of the left as for the start of the right.

But the real problem is that you increment `i` and `j` without checking whether you've walked off the end of `left` or `right`, so you eventually get an index error.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check if you've consumed all the elements in a list already, and extend by the rest of the other if you have.

Answer (score 1):

To make the issue a little more obvious, think about if your lists end up being something like this:

```
right = [1, 2, 3, 4]
left = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Then you will append all of `right` before you reach the end of `left` - but you will still try to see if `right[5] < left[0]` - which will give the error you see. You need to add a check for when either of the lists is exhausted - something like:

```
if i >= len(right):
   newArray.extend(left)
   break
```

and similarly for the `j >= len(left)` case.